# How to get a list of files using utf-8 characters in PHP 5.6?

Tags: php, utf-8, glob

I am Vietnamese and I want to use PHP to get a list of files in a directory that uses utf-8 characters.

My hope output is an array of files: `array("music/Nhạc Thiền Tĩnh Tâm 1.mp3","music/Nhạc Thiền Tĩnh Tâm 2.mp3","music/Nhạc Thiền Tĩnh Tâm 3.mp3","...");`

My code:

```
<?php
foreach (glob("music/*.mp3") as $ds) {
    echo $ds . "<br>";
}
```

I use the `glob()` function.My hope output is an array of files: array("music/Nhạc Thiền Tĩnh Tâm 1.mp3","music/Nhạc Thiền Tĩnh Tâm 2.mp3","music/Nhạc Thiền Tĩnh Tâm 3.mp3","...");
But the return list is an empty array. How can I do that in PHP 5.6 on Windows? Please help me!

Comment: Can you add your code and the directory structure?

Comment: My folder: abc / which contains the files:
Tập tin 1.mp3
Tập tin 2.mp3
Tập tin 3.mp3
...
<?php
foreach (glob("abc/*.mp3") as $ds) {
    echo $ds . "<br>";
}

Comment: And this script is located in the dir where these files are located? ...edit, or rather one dir above so `abc/` is at the correct path?

Comment: oh no, file get_list.php contains the code on the same level as the abc directory

Comment: That sounds like it should work then. What if you use an absolute path, same result? What about `scandir`? The utf issue should only come into affect for displaying, or possibly trying to process the file. For just echoing you should have the black diamond if the file was using an incorrect charset.

Comment: I want to list the files in that directory to handle them. There is nothing if there are only 1 or 2 files in that folder, but it will be different if there are thousands of files in that folder, I can't do it manually, that's crazy! I want to make them automatically. I use the glob () function to execute, but what happened to it? It's an empty array, and I don't know how to do it next?
Anyway thank you for your enthusiasm !!!

Comment: I mean absolute to the path `glob("/var/stuff/things/abc/*.mp3")` or `scandir` and `print_r` the result just for testing.

Comment: I use the absolute path, and the result is an empty array, I don't know why the glob () function doesn't work with filenames with such characters. If folder abc has abc.mp3 file, the glob () function returns abc/abc.mp3 but the file name is "âm nhạc.mp3" then it does not return abc/âm nhạc.mp3

Comment: Maybe I'll have to find another way to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: There is the second method I've mentioned twice.

Comment: Do you mention function scandir(). I will try it :)

Comment: I use scandir (), but the result is output font error: 
Nh?c Thi?n T?nh T?m 1.mp3
Nh?c Thi?n T?nh T?m 2.mp3
Nh?c Thi?n T?nh T?m 3.mp3
I have also used iconv() and mb_convert_encoding() but the filename still has errors

Comment: Your page is not encoded as UTF8 convert that and you should be good to go.

Comment: @user3783243 I don't understand, do you have any solution for this?  
I also checked the php.ini file and put the title in my code:  
`<?php
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
foreach (scandir("music") as $file_name) {
    echo iconv('windows-1258', 'utf-8', $file_name) . "<br>";
}`
and my output is:
**.
..
Nh?c Thi?n T?nh Tâm 1.mp3
Nh?c Thi?n T?nh Tâm 2.mp3
Nh?c Thi?n T?nh Tâm 3.mp3**

Comment: I'm not familiar with `windows-1258` this is kind of a different question though at that point.

Comment: It is a Vietnamese character encoder. You can see more here: http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-utf8.html#findcharset
My output still fails. I still can't fix it.